# disable strict mode in drools

Tags: java, drools

I'm getting error like `Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: ...`
I've added system property `drools.dialect.mvel.strict=false`
I can see system property was applied to my app in jvisualvm
But I'm getting the same error with 'using strict-mode'.

How could I disable strict mode in drools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it can be done from Java:

```
  KnowledgeBuilderConfiguration kbConfig =
        KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilderConfiguration();

    kbConfig.setProperty("drools.dialect.mvel.strict", "false");

    KnowledgeBuilder kBuilder =
        KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder( kbConfig );
```

Although, setting the property should be OK. -- Maybe a look at the error might help to find a workaround?

Comment: I had the same problem... I set the system property but had no effect.. What did I do wrong?