# Drools 6.1 - How to disable strict mode?

Tags: drools, kie, mvel

**Short version:** How can I disable the MVEL strict mode using the new KIE API?

I know that there is a configuration property "drools.dialect.mvel.strict" [that can be set using the old KnowledgeBuilder API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934723/disable-strict-mode-in-drools). However I can not find a way to accomplish the same with the new API.

**Long version:** I have an object method, called *Object attribute(String name)*, and the result can be many different types. Sometimes could be a List, others String or whatever. Now in order to use that method I have to use a lot of casting or drools throws exceptions. For the following example:

```
$entity : RootEntity( attribute('authors') != null && 
                      attribute('authors').size() >= 3 && 
                      attribute('authors')[2] == 'whatever' )
```

I get errors like this:

```
Unable to Analyse Expression attribute("authors").size() >= 3:
[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: java.lang.Object.size()]

Unable to Analyse Expression attribute("authors")[2] == "whatever":
[Error: unknown collection type: class java.lang.Object; property=]
```

In order to make this work with the strict typing enabled I have to type the same expression as such:

```
$entity : RootEntity( attribute('authors') != null && 
                      ((java.util.List) attribute('authors')).size() >= 3 && 
                      ((java.util.List) attribute('authors'))[2] == 'whatever' )
```

Which can be disabled with the strict typing option.

Comment: This pattern works, exaclty as shown, with some 5.x version? How is `attribute` defined?

Comment: public Object attribute(String attribute) {
/* resolve the actual value */
}

Comment: Yes, casting works but is not ideal. Drools/MVEL can also process dynamic expressions without the need to cast. For that to work I need to find the way to set the "drools.dialect.mvel.strict" to false (using the new KIE API instead of the old KnowledgeBuilder API). That is the question.

Comment: I meant the *first* pattern, the one without the casts. Did this work, exactly as shown, with `attribute()` returning an Object? Which Drools version can handle that?

Comment: Any luck/updates with this question? Facing the same problem myself. Can't seem to find any solid support in the docs.