# How can I set drools.dialect.mvel.strict to false when using KieSessions in Drools 6.5?

Tags: java, drools

I just want to turn off strict-mode. This question has the old way of doing it: [disable strict mode in drools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934723/disable-strict-mode-in-drools?noredirect=1&lq=1) . I would like to do it in Java or in the kmodule.xml, or a properties file, not in the jvm args if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the `<configuration>` element in kmodule.xml to set properties:

```
<kmodule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.drools.org/xsd/kmodule">
  <configuration>
    <property key="drools.dialect.mvel.strict" value="false" />
  </configuration>
  ...
</kmodule>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that , as well as many other things, including kieBaseConfiguration and KieSessionConfiguration. The dialect settings inside the ksession when debugging say it is false but drools still runs as if it is in strict-mode giving "cannot resolve using strict-mode" errors. I decided to cut my losses and refactored all my rules to work in strict mode. Thank you for your help though.